# AMQP - Apache Qpid client for Node.js

Tags: node.js, amqp, qpid

I've been trying to find an Apache Qpid client for Node.js.

There is this [node-qpid](https://www.npmjs.org/package/qpid) package I found but it's too old and doesn't install even with qpid-proton-C 0.3 as mentioned in the README.

I just basically want an AMQP client for Node.js that can successfully talk to a QPID C++ Broker.

Most AMQP clients like this one([amqplib](https://www.npmjs.org/package/amqplib))(AMQP 0-9-1) i found for Node.js aren't interoperable with QPID C++ Broker (AMQP 1-0 and 0-10).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of google searching, this is what I found.

**Javascript binding for Qpid Proton C**

https://apache.googlesource.com/qpid-proton/+/fadams-javascript-binding

Follow the Instructions here to use it with node.js:

https://apache.googlesource.com/qpid-proton/+/fadams-javascript-binding/proton-c/bindings/javascript/README

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

I have written a modular amqp client, [bramqp](https://github.com/bakkerthehacker/bramqp), that has support for connecting to qpid brokers.

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in a module that can connect natively (without a websocket requirement) you can also check out [amqp10](http://github.com/noodlefrenzy/node-amqp10)